# Let user create and send a doodle

Tags: javascript, contact-form

I have been searching for this all over, but haven't found anything similar, and all searches to do with doodles are filled with google doodle search results, which isn't what I'm looking for.

A client recently came to me with an idea she had for a contact form, where her customer gets to create a small doodle, and send it to her. She could then display everyones doodles on a page on the site.

She got the idea from Number 5 on this page... http://www.blogtyrant.com/best-contact-us-pages/ but that site has been updated since the article was written, and no longer have the doodle box on the contact form, so I can't just use dev tools to see how they did it.

Has anyone seen something like this before? Or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds a bit like the draw a pig thing which went around... so, what's your question exactly?

Comment: Depending on what kind of browser compatibility you need HTML5 canvases could be a great way to do this. Basically you create (or find) a drawing tool using canvases and then it can be saved as a file and sent. The hardest part would be the drawing tool...

Comment: Sounds like coupling [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) with a little bit of Javascript (OnSubmit) to save the image as a byte array/base64 in to a hidden field (then proceed to submit)

Comment: @liath Just to know if anyone has seen something similar that I can use as a base to start from to make a version for my site. I'm not seeing much for "draw a pig", just a few flash games.

Comment: I've seen `canvas.toDataURL()` method being used in a doodle app. The string can be easily saved in a DB and displayed later by setting it as `src` of an `img` tag